# Opening symlink to .txt file results in permission denied on MAC OS X

Tags: macos, shell, file-permissions, symlink, permission-denied

Assume I have two folders and a `.txt` file in a directory such that

```
/folder1/file.txt
/folder2
```

Being currently in `folder1` I create a symlink with `ln -s file.txt ../folder2/`. If a now `cd`into `folder2` and open the symbolic link in vim with `vim file.txt` the editor opens with an empty file prompting `"test.txt" [Permission Denied]`in the status bar. Additionally the file only open in "readonly" mode. Is there a way to create a working symlink. I am on Mac OS X.

Update: 
`ls -lR` on the original file results in `-rw-r--r--` and for the symlink I obtain `lrwxr-xr-x`.

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `ls -lR folder{1,2}` so we can see the permissions involved.

Comment: Symlinks don't bypass permissions. If you don't have permission to open `/folder2/file.txt`, you won't have permission to open `/folder1/file.txt`, either. Keep in mind that permissions (or even the existence of the source) aren't checked when the symlink is created; the source is just a string.

Comment: I do have the permissions to open and edit the original file.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest trying to enter the complete path to the target. e.g.

```
ln -s /folder1/file.txt ../folder2/
```

The path to the link can be relative.